# I am unable to display table data dynamically using jSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following code in component.ts

```
{
  Sheet1:
    [
      0:{Name: "foo", Age: "24", __rowNum__: 1},
      1:{Name: "boo", Age: "14", __rowNum__: 2}
    ]
}
```

This data is kept in this.tableData array

I put all the keys into one array as I need to display headers of the table dynamically

```
this.tableHeaders= Object.keys(this.data['Sheet1'][0]);
```

My tableHeaders output would look like the following

```
["Name", "Age"]
```

And I kept all the data I need to display in table in another array

`this.data = this.tableData['Sheet1'];`

Now I want to display all this data in a table which am doing like the following

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">
        {{header}}                         //able to display headers
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let header of importedData">
                <td *ngFor="let item of data">{{header[item.value]}}</td>
            </tr> //here I want to display table data based on header value
 </table
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: {{item[header.value]}} ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">
           | {{header}}
       </th>
    </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
            <td *ngFor="let key of tableHeaders">{{row[key]}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This will do the job!

EDIT:
beware that your code

```
{
    Sheet1:
        [
            0:{Name: "foo", Age: "24", __rowNum__: 1},
            1:{Name: "boo", Age: "14", __rowNum__: 2}
    ]
}
```

is not valid. You must remove 0 and 1 before those nested objects in Sheet1 array first. This is valid object:

```
{
    Sheet1:
        [
            {Name: "foo", Age: "24", __rowNum__: 1},
            {Name: "boo", Age: "14", __rowNum__: 2}
    ]
}
```